# SQL Query: join with condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables:

```
           Customer
|   c_id   |      name      |  
| -------- | -------------- |
|  1       | Adam           |
|  2       | Bradley        |
|  3       | Chandler       |
|  4       | Damian         |
|  5       | Eric           |
|  6       | Frank          |
```

```
           orders
| order_id |    c_id        |      amount
| -------- | -------------- | -------------- |
|  1       | 1              | 50
|  2       | 1              | 2
|  3       | 2              | 15
|  4       | 2              | 22
|  5       | 2              | 10
|  6       | 2              | 7
|  7       | 3              | 7
|  8       | 3              | 2
|  9       | 5              | 18
|  10      | 5              | 24
|  11      | 6              | 60
|  12      | 6              | 1
```

I want to create a list of users who have order amounts over 50.

This list should include c_id, name and the sum of all their orders including those under 50.

so it should look like this:

```
| c_id     |    name        |      amount
| -------- | -------------- | -------------- |
|  1       |Adam            | 52
|  6       | Frank          | 61
```

Comment: On a side note: *Over* 50 would be `> 50`. You seem to want 50 *or more*, i.e. `>= 50`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Yes, you're correct. Thanks for the spot :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select c.c_id, c.name, sum(o.amount)
from orders o join
     customers c
     on o.c_id = c.c_id
group by c.c_id, c.name
having max(o.amount) > 50;
```

Comment: I think I was unclear so I've re-phrased and included a table of what I want it to look like. If you can please try it again.

Comment: @terrence876 : This should work just fine. Just join the customer table, if you want to see the name.

Comment: @thorstenkettner how do I join correctly? I keep getting 'Error in query (1052): Column 'user_id' in field list is ambiguous''

with the following code:

 select user_id, sum(amount)
from ORDERS
join Customer on Customer.user_id = ORDERS.user_id
group by user_id
having max(amount) >= 100;

Answer (score 0):

Best to break this down into chunks:

Customers who have a total amount over 50:

```
 SELECT user_id FROM orders GROUP BY user_id HAVING sum(amount) >= 50;
```

Sum of the amounts for each order for customers that meet the criteria above:

```
 SELECT user_id, sum(amount) as order_total 
 FROM orders
 WHERE user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM orders HAVING sum(amount) >= 50 GROUP BY user_id)
 GROUP BY user_id;
```

You can just join over to your customer table to grab the name. Didn't include since that is the more straightforward ask here.

Comment: I think I was unclear so I've re-phrased and included a table of what I want it to look like. If you can please try it again.

Comment: Just remove `order_id` from that second query (in both the select and group by). Ultimately the logic is the same 1) figure out how to identify these users 2) get the data for the users that you need. The rest of it is just decoration.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  c_id
, name
, SUM(amount) AS total_amount
FROM
  orders a
  INNER JOIN customer b
  ON b.c_id = a.user_id
WHERE
    c_id IN (
    SELECT
      user_id
    FROM
      orders
    WHERE
      amount >= 50)
GROUP BY c_id, name
```

Comment: No. You are missing a `GROUP BY` clause. And there is no need for `DISTINCT` with `IN` (and should be avoided) , and the subquery is not needed either, because `HAVING` suffices, as shown in Gordon's answer.

Comment: I think I was unclear so I've re-phrased and included a table of what I want it to look like. If you can please try it again.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Yes, agreed that Gordon's answer is the most concise. Modified my answer to fix syntax errors. Out of curiosity, why is using DISTINCT in the subquery paired with IN to be avoided? Performance?

Comment: Well, with SQL you are suposed to tell the DBMS what to look for, not how to do it. With `DISTINCT` you are trying to force the DBMS to make the customer list distinct first (which, if the DBMS obeys could be costly). Let the DBMS decide how to execute that `IN` clause. Internally it may indeed create a distinct list. Or it may look up rows in a loop. We should not care.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.